# SQLite PDO :memory: save database to file

Tags: php, file, sqlite, memory, pdo

i'm working with a SQLite in PHP database that way:

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:products.sqlite');
```

i've to do many INSERT query, but it looks like those operation slow down the process a little bit. i know that i can store the database in memory with:

```
$dbmem = new PDO('sqlite::memory:');
```

but at the end of the process i want to store db on disk.
i can't find a way to do that.
is that possible?how?
thanks

Comment: You could create a backup of your table just to make sure your data is safe. You could also insert the data from your memory table to a disk based table, but I guess it'd take the same amount of time than using a disk based table in the first place. Take a look a this thread http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Saving-a-memory-based-SQLite-database-to-disk-td44225.html

Comment: Pretty sure you'd have to insert into a db stored on disk manually http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

Comment: So your *actual* problem is low INSERT performance? Have you tried wrapping all these INSERTs into one transaction?

Comment: @CL thanks, that reduced the execution time by far :)

Comment: @JacopoGrassi as CL said - avoid using insert in loops; use insert into ... values to boost performance

Comment: Duplicate question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163082/writing-a-sqlite-db-loaded-using-memory-to-disk