# Writing a SQLite db loaded using :memory to disk

Tags: php, database, sqlite

I'm generating quite a substantial (~50Mb) SQLite3 database in memory that I need to be able to write to disk once the generation of said database is complete. What is the best way of approaching this using PHP?

I have tried creating a structurally identical SQLite3 db on disk, and then using INSERTS to populate it, but it is far too slow. I have also drawn a blank looking at the online [PHP SQLite3 docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php).

What I have found is the [SQLite3 Backup API](http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html), but not sure how best to approach interfacing with it from PHP. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The backup API is not available in PHP.

If you wrap all INSERTs into a single transaction, the speed should be OK.

You could avoid the separate temporay database and make the disk database almost as fast by [increasing the page cache size](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_cache_size) to be larger than 50 MB, [disabling journaling](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode), and [disabling synchronous writes](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_synchronous).